# Recursive python function - can't calculate edge case

Tags: python, python-2.7, recursion

I have the following dictionary:

```
>>> for key, details in relationships.items():
                print key, details[2]

('INVOICE', 'INVOICE') 1
('INVOICE', 'ORDER2') 0.50000000
('INVOICE', 'ORDER1') 0.01536410
('ORDER1', 'ORDER2') 0.05023163
('INVOICE', 'ORDER4') 0.00573215
('ORDER4', 'ORDER1') 0.08777898
('ORDER4', 'ORDER3') 0.01674388
```

This creates the following hierarchy:

```
INVOICE -> ORDER2
        -> ORDER1 -> ORDER2
        -> ORDER4 -> ORDER1 -> ORDER2
                  -> ORDER3
```

where each arrow represents the value of `details[2]`.  The final 'relationship' of each order to the invoice needs to be calculated.  Expected values:

```
> ORDER1: 0.01586726 (0.0153641 + 0.0877898 x 0.00573215) 
> ORDER2: 0.50079704 (0.5 + 0.05023163 x 0.0153641 + 0.05023163 x 0.0877898 x 0.00573215)
> ORDER3: 0.00009598 (0.01674388 x 0.00573215)
> ORDER4: 0.00573215 (0.00573215)
```

I have the following attempt at a recursive function:

```
for invoice in final_relationships.keys():
     calculate(invoice, invoice, Decimal(1))

def calculate(orig_ord, curr_ord, contribution):
     for rel_ID, rel_details in relationships.items():
          if rel_ID[1] == curr_ord:
               if orig_ord == curr_ord:
                    contribution = Decimal(1)
               if rel_ID[0] != rel_ID[1]:
                    contribution = (contribution * rel_details[2]).quantize(Decimal('0.00000001'), rounding=ROUND_HALF_UP)
                    calculate(orig_ord, rel_ID[0], contribution)
               else:
                    final_relationships[orig_ord] += contribution
                    contribution = Decimal(0)
```

This correctly calculates all scenarios except one, for ORDER2.

```
------- ORDER2
1  # rel_ID,               curr_ord,     rel_details[2],    contribution
2  ('ORDER1', 'ORDER2')    ORDER2        0.05023163         1
3  ('INVOICE', 'ORDER1')    ORDER1        0.01536410         0.05023163
4  ('INVOICE', 'INVOICE')  INVOICE       1                  0.00077176
5  # final
6  0.00077176
7  ('ORDER4', 'ORDER1')    ORDER1        0.08777898         0.00077176
8  ('INVOICE', 'ORDER4')   ORDER4        0.00573215         0.00006774
9  ('INVOICE', 'INVOICE')  INVOICE       1                  3.9E-7
10 # final
11 0.00077215
12 ('INVOICE', 'ORDER2')   ORDER2        0.50000000         0.05023163
13 ('INVOICE', 'INVOICE')  INVOICE       1                  0.50000000
14 # final
15 0.50077215
```

The issue is on line 7, since the contribution begins at 0.00077176 instead of 0.05023163, because the iteration for ('ORDER1', 'ORDER2') doesn't happen the second time (after line 2).  This is the relationship `INVOICE -> ORDER4 -> ORDER1 -> ORDER2`.

How can I fix the function?  I tried resetting the contribution if the 'orig_ord' wasn't processed, but couldn't figure out where to put it.  If the whole thing is dumb, I'm open to re-writing, as long as I get the job done.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have to make a tree because this looks like a tree

```
INVOICE -> ORDER2
        -> ORDER1 -> ORDER2
        -> ORDER4 -> ORDER1 -> ORDER2
                  -> ORDER3
```

So i implemented [this code](https://repl.it/FHdl/27) to make the right tree

```
hierarchi = [('INVOICE', 'ORDER2'),
('INVOICE', 'ORDER1'),
('ORDER1', 'ORDER2'),
('INVOICE', 'ORDER4'),
('ORDER4', 'ORDER1'),
('ORDER4', 'ORDER3')]

def make_based_list(base):
  the_list = []
  i = 0
  for item in hierarchi:
    if(item[0] == base):
      the_list.insert(i,item)
      i+=1
  return the_list

class Node:
  def __init__(self,base):
    self.base = base
    self.children = []
    self.n_of_child = 0

  def get_child(self,base):
    found_child = Node('NOT_FOUND')
    for child in self.children:
      if child.base == base:
        found_child = child

    if found_child.base!='NOT_FOUND':
      return found_child
    else:
      for child in self.children:
        found_child = child.get_child(base)
        if found_child.base!='NOT_FOUND':
          return found_child
    return found_child

  def add_child(self,child_node):
    self.children.insert(self.n_of_child,child_node)
    self.n_of_child+=1

  def update_child(self,base,child_node):
    for child in self.children:
        if child.base == base:
          child = child_node
          return 1
    return 0

  def populate(self,assoc_list):
    for assoc in assoc_list:
      child_node = Node(assoc[1])
      self.add_child(child_node)

  def print_childrens(self):
    for child in self.children:
      child.print_me()

  def print_me(self):
    print("Me:"+self.base)
    if self.n_of_child>0:
      print("Mychilds:")
      self.print_childrens()
    else:
      print("No child")

top_base = 'INVOICE'
top_based_list = make_based_list(top_base)
top_node = Node(top_base)
top_node.populate(top_based_list)

for item in hierarchi:
  if item[0]!=top_base:
    the_child = top_node.get_child(item[1])
    the_parent = top_node.get_child(item[0])
    if the_child.base=='NOT_FOUND':
      the_child = Node(item[1])
    the_parent.add_child(the_child)
    top_node.update_child(item[0],the_parent)

top_node.print_me()
```

I am new in python and i know that the code can be better, but i just want to help
Now i'll implement your calculation and update my answer
I hope that's useful for you